# how can i detect and track baseball bat using opencv?

Tags: opencv, haar-classifier

I want to detect and track so i did experiment using optical flow and goodFindToTrack

but i didn't get result

Is it possible to detect and track baseball bat using cascading haarlike or hog

I just want bat's angle of each frame

The IDE is visual studio 2013 and I'm using C/C++.

Detecting camera is pi-cam

Comment: Can you provide with some sample input ?

Comment: I don't think Haar detection suits this problem well. Maybe HoG but you will have to make the detection invariant to rotation and maybe perspective distortion. Or you assume some pose and use real tracking after detection instead of "tracking by detection"

Answer (score 1):

Position Tracking Depends on the type of the base ball 
You can easily track the path of the base ball.Here is the sample code for ball tracking by using Kalman Filter

```
// Module "core"
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>

// Module "highgui"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

// Module "imgproc"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

// Module "video"
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>

// Output
#include <iostream>

// Vector
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// >>>>> Color to be tracked
#define MIN_H_BLUE 200
#define MAX_H_BLUE 300
// <<<<< Color to be tracked


int main()
{
    // Camera frame
    cv::Mat frame;

    // >>>> Kalman Filter
    int stateSize = 6;
    int measSize = 4;
    int contrSize = 0;

    unsigned int type = CV_32F;
    cv::KalmanFilter kf(stateSize, measSize, contrSize, type);

    cv::Mat state(stateSize, 1, type);  // [x,y,v_x,v_y,w,h]
    cv::Mat meas(measSize, 1, type);    // [z_x,z_y,z_w,z_h]
    //cv::Mat procNoise(stateSize, 1, type)
    // [E_x,E_y,E_v_x,E_v_y,E_w,E_h]

    // Transition State Matrix A
    // Note: set dT at each processing step!
    // [ 1 0 dT 0  0 0 ]
    // [ 0 1 0  dT 0 0 ]
    // [ 0 0 1  0  0 0 ]
    // [ 0 0 0  1  0 0 ]
    // [ 0 0 0  0  1 0 ]
    // [ 0 0 0  0  0 1 ]
    cv::setIdentity(kf.transitionMatrix);

    // Measure Matrix H
    // [ 1 0 0 0 0 0 ]
    // [ 0 1 0 0 0 0 ]
    // [ 0 0 0 0 1 0 ]
    // [ 0 0 0 0 0 1 ]
    kf.measurementMatrix = cv::Mat::zeros(measSize, stateSize, type);
    kf.measurementMatrix.at<float>(0) = 1.0f;
    kf.measurementMatrix.at<float>(7) = 1.0f;
    kf.measurementMatrix.at<float>(16) = 1.0f;
    kf.measurementMatrix.at<float>(23) = 1.0f;

    // Process Noise Covariance Matrix Q
    // [ Ex   0   0     0     0    0  ]
    // [ 0    Ey  0     0     0    0  ]
    // [ 0    0   Ev_x  0     0    0  ]
    // [ 0    0   0     Ev_y  0    0  ]
    // [ 0    0   0     0     Ew   0  ]
    // [ 0    0   0     0     0    Eh ]
    //cv::setIdentity(kf.processNoiseCov, cv::Scalar(1e-2));
    kf.processNoiseCov.at<float>(0) = 1e-2;
    kf.processNoiseCov.at<float>(7) = 1e-2;
    kf.processNoiseCov.at<float>(14) = 5.0f;
    kf.processNoiseCov.at<float>(21) = 5.0f;
    kf.processNoiseCov.at<float>(28) = 1e-2;
    kf.processNoiseCov.at<float>(35) = 1e-2;

    // Measures Noise Covariance Matrix R
    cv::setIdentity(kf.measurementNoiseCov, cv::Scalar(1e-1));
    // <<<< Kalman Filter

    // Camera Index
    int idx = 0;

    // Camera Capture
    cv::VideoCapture cap;

    // >>>>> Camera Settings
    if (!cap.open(idx))
    {
        cout << "Webcam not connected.\n" << "Please verify\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1024);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 768);
    // <<<<< Camera Settings

    cout << "\nHit 'q' to exit...\n";

    char ch = 0;

    double ticks = 0;
    bool found = false;

    int notFoundCount = 0;

    // >>>>> Main loop
    while (ch != 'q' && ch != 'Q')
    {
        double precTick = ticks;
        ticks = (double) cv::getTickCount();

        double dT = (ticks - precTick) / cv::getTickFrequency(); //seconds

        // Frame acquisition
        cap >> frame;

        cv::Mat res;
        frame.copyTo( res );

        if (found)
        {
            // >>>> Matrix A
            kf.transitionMatrix.at<float>(2) = dT;
            kf.transitionMatrix.at<float>(9) = dT;
            // <<<< Matrix A

            cout << "dT:" << endl << dT << endl;

            state = kf.predict();
            cout << "State post:" << endl << state << endl;

            cv::Rect predRect;
            predRect.width = state.at<float>(4);
            predRect.height = state.at<float>(5);
            predRect.x = state.at<float>(0) - predRect.width / 2;
            predRect.y = state.at<float>(1) - predRect.height / 2;

            cv::Point center;
            center.x = state.at<float>(0);
            center.y = state.at<float>(1);
            cv::circle(res, center, 2, CV_RGB(255,0,0), -1);

            cv::rectangle(res, predRect, CV_RGB(255,0,0), 2);
        }

        // >>>>> Noise smoothing
        cv::Mat blur;
        cv::GaussianBlur(frame, blur, cv::Size(5, 5), 3.0, 3.0);
        // <<<<< Noise smoothing

        // >>>>> HSV conversion
        cv::Mat frmHsv;
        cv::cvtColor(blur, frmHsv, CV_BGR2HSV);
        // <<<<< HSV conversion

        // >>>>> Color Thresholding
        // Note: change parameters for different colors
        cv::Mat rangeRes = cv::Mat::zeros(frame.size(), CV_8UC1);
        cv::inRange(frmHsv, cv::Scalar(MIN_H_BLUE / 2, 100, 80),
                    cv::Scalar(MAX_H_BLUE / 2, 255, 255), rangeRes);
        // <<<<< Color Thresholding

        // >>>>> Improving the result
        cv::erode(rangeRes, rangeRes, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);
        cv::dilate(rangeRes, rangeRes, cv::Mat(), cv::Point(-1, -1), 2);
        // <<<<< Improving the result

        // Thresholding viewing
        cv::imshow("Threshold", rangeRes);

        // >>>>> Contours detection
        vector<vector<cv::Point> > contours;
        cv::findContours(rangeRes, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,
                         CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
        // <<<<< Contours detection

        // >>>>> Filtering
        vector<vector<cv::Point> > balls;
        vector<cv::Rect> ballsBox;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::Rect bBox;
            bBox = cv::boundingRect(contours[i]);

            float ratio = (float) bBox.width / (float) bBox.height;
            if (ratio > 1.0f)
                ratio = 1.0f / ratio;

            // Searching for a bBox almost square
            if (ratio > 0.75 && bBox.area() >= 400)
            {
                balls.push_back(contours[i]);
                ballsBox.push_back(bBox);
            }
        }
        // <<<<< Filtering

        cout << "Balls found:" << ballsBox.size() << endl;

        // >>>>> Detection result
        for (size_t i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++)
        {
            cv::drawContours(res, balls, i, CV_RGB(20,150,20), 1);
            cv::rectangle(res, ballsBox[i], CV_RGB(0,255,0), 2);

            cv::Point center;
            center.x = ballsBox[i].x + ballsBox[i].width / 2;
            center.y = ballsBox[i].y + ballsBox[i].height / 2;
            cv::circle(res, center, 2, CV_RGB(20,150,20), -1);

            stringstream sstr;
            sstr << "(" << center.x << "," << center.y << ")";
            cv::putText(res, sstr.str(),
                        cv::Point(center.x + 3, center.y - 3),
                        cv::FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, CV_RGB(20,150,20), 2);
        }
        // <<<<< Detection result

        // >>>>> Kalman Update
        if (balls.size() == 0)
        {
            notFoundCount++;
            cout << "notFoundCount:" << notFoundCount << endl;
            if( notFoundCount >= 100 )
            {
                found = false;
            }
            /*else
                kf.statePost = state;*/
        }
        else
        {
            notFoundCount = 0;

            meas.at<float>(0) = ballsBox[0].x + ballsBox[0].width / 2;
            meas.at<float>(1) = ballsBox[0].y + ballsBox[0].height / 2;
            meas.at<float>(2) = (float)ballsBox[0].width;
            meas.at<float>(3) = (float)ballsBox[0].height;

            if (!found) // First detection!
            {
                // >>>> Initialization
                kf.errorCovPre.at<float>(0) = 1; // px
                kf.errorCovPre.at<float>(7) = 1; // px
                kf.errorCovPre.at<float>(14) = 1;
                kf.errorCovPre.at<float>(21) = 1;
                kf.errorCovPre.at<float>(28) = 1; // px
                kf.errorCovPre.at<float>(35) = 1; // px

                state.at<float>(0) = meas.at<float>(0);
                state.at<float>(1) = meas.at<float>(1);
                state.at<float>(2) = 0;
                state.at<float>(3) = 0;
                state.at<float>(4) = meas.at<float>(2);
                state.at<float>(5) = meas.at<float>(3);
                // <<<< Initialization

                found = true;
            }
            else
                kf.correct(meas); // Kalman Correction

            cout << "Measure matrix:" << endl << meas << endl;
        }
        // <<<<< Kalman Update

        // Final result
        cv::imshow("Tracking", res);

        // User key
        ch = cv::waitKey(1);
    }
    // <<<<< Main loop

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

According to the shape of bat u can get the coordinates of the bat